# TailwindCSS doesn't work on Netlify after deploying

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, netlify

in the local server the project run fine but after deployed from GitHub to nullify its stop loading the CSS
[GithubRepo](https://github.com/smsi80/todolist)
[Netlifylink](https://todolistsmsi.netlify.app/)
what i get
[image: netlify]
what its must to be
[image: Local]

i tried to change the directory moving all src files to gather nothing works

Firefox console
[image]

google chrome console [image]

Comment: i change the index.HTML place to root directory and changed the tailwind config its seams to work

Answer (score 1):

The 'npm install' command should be compulsory to run on the server. so that it can store and execute all the packages used in the project

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HYmae2d
build page on netlify
but no chenges